# How does echo `echo \\\\\\\z` result in \\z?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, escaping, echo

I'm trying to understand this behavior:

```
bash-5.1$ echo `echo \\\\\\\z`
\\z
```

For the inner echo command, 1st escape character (`\`) would escape the leading escape character (2nd one), and it repeats with 3rd escaping 4rth, and 5th escaping 6th. Shouldn't the 7th escape character escape the leading z character, leading to `\\\z` which under the influence of outer echo would lead to `\z` as the answer?

NOTE : - If the last \ will not escape the z (which could be the possible case as I'm assuming from seeing the answer), then why is that?

Comment: My shell outputs `\\\z`. It's not clear what you're talking about in regards to "inner" and "outer" echo here or which "above bash related question" you're referring to.

Comment: Bash outputs `\\z` on my system and the "above bash related question" refers to the title, which has an outer and inner echo via command substitution:  ``echo `echo \\\\\\\z` ``. I clarified and nominated for reopen.

Answer (score 1):

> How does `` echo `echo \\\\\\\z` `` result in `\\z`?

Syntax tree looks like this:

#### - `echo` -> `` ` `` -> `echo` -> `\\\\\\\z`

We start from `\\\\\\\z`. Firstly https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Escape-Character.html#Escape-Character happens:

> A non-quoted backslash ‘\’ is the Bash escape character. It preserves the literal value of the next character that follows [...]

The `\\\\\\z` is unquoted, so we transform each pair `\?` to `?`, like `\\` into `\` and `\z` into `z`.

```
\\\\\\\z
^^|||||| -> \
  ^^|||| -> \
    ^^|| -> \
      ^^ -> z
```

#### - `echo` -> `` ` `` -> `echo` -> `\\\z`

Then `` `...` `` backquotes happen, one of the reasons why `$(..)` is preferred for command substitution. From https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution :

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by ‘$’, ‘`’, or ‘\’.

In `\\\z` the first `\` is followed by `\`, so it's meaning is not literal. The meaning of the first `\` is, as in the previous point, it preserves the literal value of the next character. So, basically, `\\` is replaced by a single `\`. The rest `\z` is preserved literally.

```
\\\z
^^    -> \
  ..  -> \z
```

#### - `echo` -> `` ` `` -> `echo` -> `\\z`

Then `echo '\\z'` is executed, and it outputs `\\z` and the command substitution `` `...` `` is replaced by the output of the command inside, so, well, by `\\z`.

#### - `echo` -> `\\z`

Then `echo '\\z'` once again outputs `\\z`.